# Assigning divisions and subdivisions (A.1 and A.1.1) to data in a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have an example input of the following data in a file.

```
      start  end
chr1   100   300
chr2   200   400
```

The "start" and "end" indicate the length of the region. So, for "chr1" the region length is 200. For "chr2" the length is 200.
I assigned each "chr" region with a "name" using `awk'{print$0 "\tA." NR}` to produce :

```
      start  end  name
chr1   100   300  A.1
chr2   200   400  A.2
```

What I want to do next is to break chr1 into 2 parts by splitting region length into 100 each, and named each part with A.1.1 and A.1.2 (to indicate that they used to be 1 part, but is split into 2). And the same with "chr2." So that they look like this:

```
      start end  name
chr1   100  200  A.1.1
chr1   201  300  A.1.2
chr2   200  300  A.2.1
chr2   301  400  A.2.2
```

So, my question is for the very last part. Would it be possible to use awk or something that can work with awk (since I already use awk for the first part) to solve this? if so, how would you do that?

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Post some sample input to go with your sample output and explain the transformation as it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following input:

```
chr1   100   300
chr2   200   400
```

I have kept the script simple so that you can follow what exactly is being done. You can bypass the intermediate step you are doing as the following will get that done.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
{
    offset = 0;
    range = int(($3-$2)/100);
    start = $2;
    end = $3;
    for (iter=1; iter<=range; iter++) {
        print $1, start+offset, (iter==range?end:start+100), "A."NR"."iter;
        offset = 1;
        start+=100
    }
}' file
chr1    100    200    A.1.1
chr1    201    300    A.1.2
chr2    200    300    A.2.1
chr2    301    400    A.2.2
```

We create three variables, `iter`, `start`, and `end` that gets initialized to 0 for every line. We calculate the range from `start` and `end`. We loop for the range to print column1, start range, start+100 along with character `A` followed by line number and the iteration number.

We initialize the offset to 1 so that next range doesn't start from the end of first.

There is a ternary test `(iter==range?end:start+100)` which basically checks if we are towards the end of range. If we are we use the end number. This is to handle cases where your lines would be `chr1 100 150` etc.

Comment: This works great! thanks Jaypal! So, just to make sure, the "offset" is used to compensate the next number after a whole number...right? In this example, after 200 the offset would make the next "start" starts at 201 ? Could you explain further on the (iter==range?end:start+100), I'd like to know what the "start+100" in it is for. Thanks so much for the explanation for the rest of the code! appreciate it.

Comment: @Andrianw Yes, that is correct. The `(iter==range?end:start+100)` is a ternary operator similar to `if-then-else` condition. If the condition `iter==range` is true (`?`) then it puts value of `end` else (`:`) it puts value of `start+100`.  You can read more about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conditional-Exp)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1!=prev{++cnt} {print $0 "\tA." cnt "." ++seen[$1]; prev=$1}' file
chr1   100  200 A.1.1
chr1   201  300 A.1.2
chr2   200  300 A.2.1
chr2   301  400 A.2.2
```

Comment: I used the sample output the OP provided but removed the final field from each line. I assume in addition to adding "A." and an incrementing count each time $1 changes, he just wants to get a count of each instance of the first field appended to each line

Comment: I thought he wanted to go from first or second input and get third input. I would let him clarify though. I used the first input .. `:P`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ed. I tried your code, it works for the naming part, but not the splitting of "chr1" and "chr2" into 2 parts.

Comment: Yeah there was a 50/50 chance but writing `(s)he` gets real old!